# Is there on Tezos an equivalent tool for easy NFT mint and dapp setup like the Candy Machine on Solana or Hashlips on Ethereum?

Tags: nft

In Ethereum there is for example Hashlips: https://hashlips.online/HashLips

In Solana there is the Candy Machine: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/overview

Both are great tools with tutorials and even people that are not coders can create their NFT collections and setup a dapp with this to mint.

I am looking for something similar on Tezos. I know you can mint your NFT on OBJKT, Teia or Fxhash.. but I am looking for tools like the above not a NFT platform. Must not be all in one if there is no such thing on Tezos. Separate tool for NFT contract and collection setup for example and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I found Openminter but it seems it is not maintained. I managed to start the project but wallet connection seems not to work hmm
https://github.com/tqtezos/minter